# ¿Cómo animar el proceso Wizard multi datos con jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

> He realizado un simple **Wizard Script jQuery** funciona perfectamente al continuar con los datos, me gustaría poder añadirle el efecto del proceso en que paso se encuentra.

**Mi pregunta:**

¿Me pueden explicar cómo puedo animar el proceso que la imagen del carrito continué con el proceso `step-1` animación del proceso `item1` y así sucesivamente?

**Ejemplo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 $(".button.next").click(function() {
   //store parent
   var step = $(this).parents(".step");
   if (step.next().length) {
     step.fadeOut("slow", function() {
       step.next().fadeIn("slow");
     });
   }
   return false;
 });
 $(".button.prev").click(function() {
   var step = $(this).parents(".step");
   if (step.prev().length) {
     step.fadeOut("slow", function() {
       step.prev().fadeIn("slow");
     });
   }
   return false;
 });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    font-size: 12px;
}


.Bread {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 0;
    width: 630px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(//drh.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Site/avast/cm/images/avast/2014/breadcrumb-3.png) no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.proceso {
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 220px;
}

.proceso.active {
    color: #000;
}

.item1 {
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
}

.item2 {
    left: 160px;
}

.item3 {
    left: 335px;
}

.item4 {
    left: 475px;
}

.item5 {
    left: 565px;
}

.item6 {
    left: 635px;
}
.wrap {
    clear: both;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
.wrap label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 4px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
.wrap input,
.wrap textarea {
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}

.button {
    background: #333;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.button:hover {
    background: #888;
    color: #000;
}

br.clear-last {
    clear: both;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.step {
    display: none;
}
.step-1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="Bread">
  <li class="proceso item1 active">Carro de la compra</li>
  <li class="proceso item2">Datos de facturación</li>
  <li class="proceso item3">Metodo de pago</li>
  <li class="proceso item4">Revisión</li>
  <li class="proceso item5">Pagar</li>
  <li class="proceso item6">Pedido finalizado</li>
</ul>

<div class="step step-1">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step step-2">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Mobile</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Address</label>
    <textarea id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step step-3">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Some</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Other</label>
    <textarea id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Fields</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step step-4">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Some</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Other</label>
    <textarea id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Fields</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step step-5">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Some</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Other</label>
    <textarea id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Fields</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="step step-6">
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="name">Some</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="email">Other</label>
    <textarea id="email"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
    <label for="phone">Fields</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
</div>
<br class="clear-last" />

<div class="sub">
  <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
  <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno, primero que todo tienes que tener en cuenta que estas usando una técnica llamada sprite donde lo que haces es agrupar todas tus imágenes y luego mostrar secciones ubicando la posición y tamaño del `backgroud` de tu elemento, tal y como lo describen en http://drh.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Site/avast/cm/images/avast/2014/breadcrumb-3.png

> Un sprite de la imagen es una colección de imágenes puestas en una sola...

Ahora esta es tu imagen:

[image: Progreso de 3 etapas]

Notaras entonces que tienes tres imágenes agrupadas de mas o menos 16px de alto cada una.
Ahora has definido una clase así:

```
.Bread {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 0;
    width: 630px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(//drh.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Site/avast/cm/images/avast/2014/breadcrumb-3.png) no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Date cuenta que has definido un alto estático para la imagen y puesto que esta mide 16+16+16=48 veras una imagen truncada «que es la idea a final de cuentas», originalmente solo veras los primeros 16px de alto de tu imagen, pero si deseas cambiar esto solo debes valerte de la propiedad

`background-position: X Y;` donde X y Y indican las posición de inicio de cada eje correspondientemente, así entonces usted podrá manipular la el progreso del `step` así:

```
.Bread.step1 {    
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

[image: step 1]

```
.Bread.step2 {    
    background-position: 0 -16;
}
```

[image: step 2]

```
.Bread.step3 {    
    background-position: 0 -32;
}
```

[image: step 3]

Una vez sabiendo esto, creo que entenderás que es un poco insuficiente para un menú de mas de 3 estados, sin embargo para continuar con la temática del progreso usando JQuery mostrare un extracto modificado de tu propuesta:

```js
var posY = 0;
    
    $(".button.next").click(function () {
        var step = $(this).parents(".step");
        if (step.next().length) {
            step.fadeOut("slow", function () {
                step.next().fadeIn("slow");
                /* posicionas la imagen 16 pixeles mas abajo de la posicion actual */
                posY = posY - 16;
                $(".Bread").css("background-position",`0px ${posY}px`);
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(".button.prev").click(function () {
        var step = $(this).parents(".step");
        if (step.prev().length) {
            step.fadeOut("slow", function () {
                step.prev().fadeIn("slow");
                /* posicionas la imagen 16 pixeles mas arriba de la posicio actual */
                posY = posY + 16;
                $(".Bread").css("background-position",`0px ${posY}px`);
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

```css
.Bread {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 40px;
        right: 0;
        width: 630px;
        height: 16px;
        background: url(//drh.img.digitalriver.com/DRHM/Storefront/Site/avast/cm/images/avast/2014/breadcrumb-3.png) no-repeat;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}

.step {
        display: none;
}

.step-1 {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="Bread">
  <li class="proceso item1"></li>
  <li class="proceso item2"></li>
  <li class="proceso item3"></li>
</ul>

<div class="step step-1">step 1
  <div class="sub">
    <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step-2">step 2
  <div class="sub">
    <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="step step-3">step 3
  <div class="sub">
    <a class="button prev" href="#">Previous</a>
    <a class="button next" href="#">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que esto sea lo suficientemente ilustrativo para darte una idea de lo que buscas, quite parte del código para centrarme en las secciones importantes para esta respuesta.

Comment: Buenos días amigo, el sprite de la imagen tiene solución amigo mediante edición de algunos de estos programas Photoshop o fireworks... O a la vez solucionarlo con estilos css aplicando una barra [de progreso](https://jsfiddle.net/uLwjdps9/) ahora lo que en sí me gustaría es que me des una pista o me puedas explicar de cómo animar el proceso con jQuery.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo de como aumentar o disminuir el progreso usando JQuery, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Estoy muy interesada en sus respuestas publicadas, pero si cambio la imagen no me funciona, que tipo de imagen debe ser, la guarde localmente y no me queda.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agardeceria.

Comment: Si no crees que sea necesario abrir una nueva pregunta podríamos continuar por chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66922/nekoos

Comment: @NekoOs Amigo tengo una nueva pregunta similar pero esta vez lo he realizado de manera más simple y sencilla pero tengo el problema en cómo animar el proceso del wizard puedes echarle un ojo :) [a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/123733/c%C3%B3mo-a%C3%B1adir-clase-seg%C3%BAn-el-valor-recibido-de-php-con-jquery)

Comment: Debes hacer la pregunta si el objetivo es diferente, para que los demas se retroalimenten de ello tambien.